# I need to grab the total number of items using regex

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I grab the value 3 from "Page 1 of 3" given the below text:

```
Displaying Results Items 1 - 50 of 120, Page 1 of 3
```

If someone can briefly explain the regex that would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Expression you need consists of a `+` quantifier (one or more times - greedy), a numerical character class `[0-9]` and a capturing group `(...)`.

```
str = "Displaying Results Items 1 - 50 of 120, Page 1 of 3"
print str.match(/Page +[0-9]+ +of +([0-9]+)/)[1]
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/c7UCAt)

Explanation:

```
Page +      # Match `Page` and any number of spaces (one or more)
[0-9]+      # Then any number of digits (one or more)
 +of        # Then any number of spaces (one or more) followed by `of`
 +          # Then any number of spaces (one or more)
([0-9]+)    # Finally up to another sequence of digits - captured by constructing a capturing group
```

There is a good [reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) to learn more about RegExes.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
str.scan(/Page \d+ of (\d+)/) #=> [["3"]]
```

It is trying to match the pattern of "Page # of #" and grabbing the last capture group. This will work if you have multiples of the same pattern in the string, it will all be a part of the resulting array.